# How to apply css class to uploaded image?

Tags: php, css

Say i have code with class tag working fine:

```
<img src="img/group2.jpg" class="findface" />
```

Now when i upload file through given code and display it:

```
<?php
$target_path = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
echo'<img src="'.$target_path.'" />';
}
?>      
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="upload file" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
```

It is displaying correctly but not applying class and when i try following code it show errors.Any solution?Please help.So i can apply class code for every uploaded image along with displaying file in browser.

```
echo'<img src="'.$target_path.'" /> class="findface";
```

Comment: Why is your class outside the closing?  /> class="findface"  did you mean class="findface" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
echo'<img src="'.$target_path.'" /> class="findface";
```

try

```
echo "<img src='".$target_path."' class='findface' />";
```

Comment: Oh genius,thanx a lot it worked.I had tried almost 10 hours to do it myself but unsuccessful.How can i do this silly mistake?Anyway lots of thanx.

Answer (score 0):

there is typo

```
echo '<img src="'.$target_path.'" class="findface">';
```